# display username after login successfully in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have two user types in my registration page one is admin and another one is user,I have login page.when I logged as a admin it goes to dashboard, in dashboard I have 10 different types of components.when I logged as admin,dashboard should be display all components.but when I logged as a user dashboard should be display only 5 components(those who are  related to user).I want to display these by using sessions.can you please help me how to do this by using sessions.and when I open any component in dashboard,username should be displayed on the top of the page.

```
public function login()
 {
       $data['error'] ="Invalid Login";
       $this->load->view('auth/header');
           if($this->input->post())
             {
              $user = $this->UserModel->login($this->input->post());
               if(count($user)>0)
                    {
                     $array = array(
                             'client_id' => $user['client_id'],
                             'client_type_id'=>$user['client_type_id'],
                              'email' => $user['email'],
                              'password' => $user['password'],
                 );
    $this->session->set_userdata($array);
}
else
{
 $data["error_message"]="Invalid User Name and Password combination";
}
```

}

}

Comment: Have your database records,what are the components for each user ?

Comment: actually components means for example admin as principal admin can see all (like employees,students,jobs,placements,complaints,etc..)..student can see only  placements,college informationetc.)i gave links in my dashboard for al these pages.when i click on employees link it goes to employees page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set user info in $your_var

```
$this->session->set_userdata('user_info', $your_var);
```

pass user info in array

```
$this->data['user_info']=$this->session->userdata['user_info'];
```

distroy session user info

```
$this->session->unset_userdata("user_info");
```

Comment: can you please explain in code how to do in my login controller

Comment: i want to display that username in the top of the header

Comment: Ok, will give you 10 min pls

Comment: are you using CI template or Smarty PHP Template Engine ?

Comment: check my answer... @user3663

Comment: i used your old code its working hardik pagdhar thank you very much

Comment: ok remove your above code and post your old code (that first one you post as answer)

Comment: i have another doubt,when user directly open dashboard page through URL system should ask LOGIN page

Comment: system dosen't allow to open page  directly through URL

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39611526/ask-login-page-when-user-opens-dashboard-page-directly-through-url-in-codeignite

Comment: please open above URL

Comment: plz check your question... @user3663

Answer (score 2):

In your logging process, you can check user id and get query using id. Then you can check what are the components for logged user can access.

Get these details and put it to variable.then you can use `session`.

```
$this->session->set_userdata('set name',your variable);
```

and you can access this session anywhere you want.

```
$this->session->userdata('set name');
```

You can get `user name` via `user id`.

Comment: where i have to use this code in my login controller or view page

Comment: use this in controller,and post it to login via parameter

Comment: Great !! all the best.