# ask login page when user opens dashboard page directly through URL in CODEIGNITER

Tags: codeigniter

I have a dashboard page..if anyone opens dashboard link directly through URL system dosen't allow them to open that page..

when they open page directly through URL system should ask LOGIN..
please help me how to do this in codeigniter..

Comment: in dashboard load function check session is set. if not redirect. Simple plan

Comment: i didn't set session in my dashboard can you please explain in code how to write in my dashboard..

Comment: Check [ion auth](https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth) repository on github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of controller check session data available or not if session are not store then redirect to your login screen.
put if condition to your __construct function and check it.

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    if(! isset($this->session->userdata['user_info'])){
        redirect($this->data['admin_url'].'authentication');
        exit ;
    }
}
```

Comment: where should i write this code in dashboard controller or login controller

Comment: Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Dashboard::$data

Filename: controllers/Dashboard.php

Line Number: 11

Backtrace:

File: /home/hsingh19/public_html/fms/application/controllers/Dashboard.php
Line: 11
Function: _error_handler

File: /home/hsingh19/public_html/fms/index.php
Line: 316
Function: require_once

Comment: comment this code and check your code working or not.. i think this error are not come to put this code..

Comment: okey i see i think you put all code in __construct function are you using CI template remove  this
$this->smarty->assign("data",$this->data);
and set proper url to login screen....

Comment: my code is working.. i got error in this line when i put your code

Comment: $this->smarty->assign("data",$this->data);

Comment: redirect(base_url('../***/login'));

Comment: if(! isset($this->session->userdata['$array']))
  {
      redirect(base_url('../clg/login'));
         exit ;
        }

Comment: Not sure why you need `exit ; when its going to redirect

Comment: but when i login through login page dashboard dosen't come, it redirect me  to login page only..

Comment: in case your database connection was lost or either any other issue session disable then php exit function are work..@wolfgang1983

Comment: when are you login plz check session data then redirect dashbord.

Comment: $this->session->set_userdata($array);
  
  if($user['client_id'] == $user['client_id'])
  {
            redirect(base_url('dashboard/dashboard'));
        }

Comment: ya after login i redirect it to dashboard

Comment: where should i print session data can you please explain it in code

Comment: check your dashbord __construct function
parent::__construct();
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($this->session->userdata['user_info']);
    echo "</pre>";
    exit;
    if(! isset($this->session->userdata['user_info'])){
       redirect($this->data['admin_url'].'authentication');
       exit ;
    }

Comment: its working but i got error(undefined index $array) in this line       echo "<pre>"; print_r($this->session->userdata['$array']);

Comment: this is wrong dear..
"<pre>"; print_r($this->session->userdata['array']);
plz check wich variable to strore your session..

Comment: i have store my session to this variable user_info and i am used any where user_info
$this->session->set_userdata('user_info', $your_var);

Comment: i stored $array as variable in session

Comment: why this is wrong way check your last question...
once again i will explain 

make one array array name is $your_var and store user info to this array
$this->session->set_userdata('user_info', $your_var);
if you need login user info then print  $this->session->userdata['user_info'];

Comment: if(count($user)>0)
                        {
                         $array = array(
                                 'client_id' => $user['client_id'],
         'first_name' => $user['first_name'],
         'client_type_id'=>$user['client_type_id'],
                                  'email' => $user['email'],
                                  'password' => $user['password'],
                     );
      
        $this->session->set_userdata($array); but i stored like this in my login controller

Comment: put this
$this->session->set_userdata('user_info', $array);

Comment: used any where look like this
$var = $this->session->userdata['user_info'];
understand ?

Comment: when i put this  $this->session->set_userdata('user_info', $array);  i got this in my dahsboard page  instead of page Array
(
    [client_id] => 7735
    [first_name] => Sai
    [client_type_id] => 15
    [email] => sai@gmail.com
    [password] => 5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99
)

Comment: i just want to open dashboard page after login i don't want to display user information